# Excel If condition with multiple cells

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a multiple columns. For e.g. A1 to D1.

Values in the column could be 'true' and 'false'.

Now i want another column called result which take all the values from A1 to D1.

If any of the column values have false then the result will be failure or success.

Is there way to specify range like A1:D1 or i have to explicitly give AND conditions like A1=true AND B1 =true and so on ?

Best Regards,

Saurav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using TRUE/FALSE:

```
=IF(AND(A1:D1),"Success","Failure")
```

[image]

---

If your data is not TRUE/FALSE then you need to use `= "yourstring"`

```
=IF(AND(A1:D1="A"),"Success","Failure")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Scott that works...just one additional question...if i want to color code success with green and failure with red ...how do i do that ?

Comment: i was able to do so using conditional formatting...is there any way to activate the color function in the formula bar ? or conditional formatting is the way to achieve this ?..or probably macros

Comment: A formula cannot change the color of a cell. Conditional formatting is the way to go.

Comment: thanks again Scott..another question ...is it possible to exclude a certain column from the range ? like if A1:E1 i want to exclude D1 values from the formula.

Answer (score 0):

*Excel has many formula to solve the issue, below I would like to show few of them.*

[image]

- Formula in cell `V16`:

  ```
  =IF(COUNTIF(R16:U16,FALSE)>0,"Failure","Success")
  ```

---

- An array (CSE) formula in cell `W16`:

  ```
  {=IF(AND(EXACT(R16:U16,"TRUE")),"Success",Failure")}
  ```

*To make the formula dynamic you may use cell reference in place of value `TRUE/FALSE`.*

- An array CSE formula in cell `X16`:

  ```
  {=IF(AND(EXACT(R16:U16,R16)) ,"Success","Failure")}
  ```
- *Finish an array formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter**.*

---

*If you are handling value other than TURE & FALSE then this can be used.*

[image]

- Formula in cell `W20`:

  ```
  =IF(COUNTIF(R20:U20,R20)=COUNTA(R20:U20),"Success","Failure")
  ```

**N.B.**

*You need to adjust cell references in the formula as required.*